# resolve host dns query from guest dns server on VM

Tags: dns, virtual-machine

How can I resolve DNS queries for my windows machine using dns server on centos on virtual box. Curretnly I open network connections on windows and point the DNS to the IP address of the VM hosting the DNS. Any help would be hugely appreciated

Comment: Why do you dislike your current solution?

Comment: Because it does not work. When I ping the virtual machine using its ip address it returns a response but i cannot get the domain to be resolved by the DNS on VM. If I have set up a DNS for example.com on my virtual machine, why cannot I get it resolved from the windows (host) machine? Even though I have pointed my windows to look for DNS on the ip of the virtual machine

Comment: It sounds like your dns server may not be setup correctly & this sounds off-topic for here. With some further details you might get some help over at [su]